# How do I modify the body and fields of a page?

Tags: haskell, hakyll

Is it possible with Hakyll to modify a field such as "date", "author" and more specifically the body of a page. For example, I wish to modify or delete some part of page.

I looked at the Hakyll documentation on Hackage. There was a function called [`changeField`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-3.3.0.0/docs/Hakyll-Web-Page-Metadata.html#v:changeField) which seam to make what I want. But this function is from version 3 of Hakyll, and it doesn't exist in Hakyll 4.5.0, which I am using now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the page body, use [`withItemBody`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.0.0/docs/Hakyll-Core-Item.html#v:withItemBody) while compiling the page. You can use it, for instance, with [`withTags`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.0.0/docs/Hakyll-Web-Html.html#v:withTags) and the tools provided by the [*tagsoup*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup-0.14) package for modifying the DOM tree of an HTML page however you want.

As for metadata, as far as I am aware of, it is read-only. What you can do instead is using [`Hakyll.Web.Template.Context`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.0.0/docs/Hakyll-Web-Template-Context.html) to define your own custom contexts for filling in template fields, possibly using metadata fields to do so. The implementation of contexts such as [`dateField`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Hakyll-Web-Template-Context.html#dateField) illustrates how that might be done.